# Attempted to index "self" a nil value

Tags: lua

I am working on a powerup class for a project and when I try to run it I get an error saying "attempted to index "self" a nil value. I would really appreciate if somebody helped me. Thanks for reading!

PS: Yes, I am using colons and not dots for my Render, Init, Update functions.

````
function Powerup:init()
    -- simple positional and dimensional variables
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 11
    self.height = 11

    
    self.dy = 0
    self.dx = 0

    self.inPlay = true
end

--[[
    Expects an argument with a bounding box, be that a paddle or a brick,
    and returns true if the bounding boxes of this and the argument overlap.
]]
function Powerup:collides(target)
    
    if self.x > target.x + target.width or target.x > self.x + self.width then
        return false
    end

    if self.y > target.y + target.height or target.y > self.y + self.height then
        return false
    end 

    
    return true
end
 
function Powerup.trigger(paddle)
    if self.inPlay then 
     self.inPlay = false
    end
end

function Powerup:update(dt)
    self.x = self.x 
    self.y = self.y + self.dy * dt

      
    if self.y <= 0 then
        self.y = 0
        self.dy = -self.dy
        gSounds['wall-hit']:play()
    end
end

function Powerup:render()
    
    if self.inPlay then
       love.graphics.draw('zucc.png', self.x, self.y)
   end
end```
````

Comment: You have `Powerup.trigger` not `Powerup:trigger` and refer to self inside that function... also `Powerup:init(self)` should be `Powerup:init()`

Comment: It did not work :(

Answer (score 1):

`table.method(self)` is equal to `table:method()`, both are given `self` as the first parameter, which means that if you are using the colon `:`, you do not need to declare `self` as a parameter.

If that doesn't solve your problem, could you be more detailed and tell us exactly which line is calling for the error?

EDIT:

the reason the error is being caused is because you did not declare the variable `x` and `y` as parameters. The error is saying that "you are trying to insert the index `x` of `self` the value `x`, but the variable X does not exist, that is, you are trying to insert `nil` into the variable"

you can solve this problem by declaring the parameters in the function:

```lua
Powerup:init(x, y)
```

and then call the function, giving the values `x` and `y`, example:

```lua
Powerup:init(3,5)
```

now `self.x` is 3, and `self.y` is 5

Comment: The exact line that is causing the error is line 7. Thanks for your help man!

Comment: @ElAmoen3D what line is line 7?

Comment: @ElAmoen3D unfortunately StackOverflow does not display lines in a personalized and clear way. Could you tell us which of the lines in your presented piece of code is line 7 in your code

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The line causing the error is self.x = x

Comment: @ElAmoen3D Answer edited, take a look and see if your problem is solved